# Google Memcache vs Local disk cache?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I want to build a mobile app. Should i cache data on google cloud memcache or it's better to store data into the mobile phone local memory ?
which is faster ? and what type of data should be put in cache in the case of a mobile app ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Any data that you want to make available to your user in offline mode (device not connected to the Internet) should be cached on the device itself. You may also want to cache the data in online mode as well (e.g. an Email App may cache the emails for last 7 days) and updates the cache when the user refreshes or the server pushes new emails.

MemCache on Google Cloud is something you would use in your Application Server for caching data that does not change very often so you don't have to keep loading the same data from the database for every request, thus improving the performance.

It is always faster to access the data on the local device compared to accessing the data from Cloud.